# Why won't the last list element become an Edit Button when toggled

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

Below is my code. I have a toolbar button for enabling EditMode, when EditMode is enabled, it won't show the rest of the task details, and just be a button saying "Edit taskName" This works for the most part, except when ran, all but the last list element will be updated, but the last one will still show all details. I can't begin to understand why. I understand if you need more code parts but this should be enough imo. Also I learned SwiftUI maybe 2 weeks ago, so any bad practice or tips you see are greatly appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScheduleView: View {
    private var schedule: [Task]
    @State private var editMode = false
    @State private var editReady = false
    @State private var editTask: Task
    init(schedule: [Task]) {
        self.schedule = schedule
        self.schedule.sort()
        self.editTask = Task(taskString: "")
    }
    var body: some View {           
            List{
                ForEach(schedule,id: \.self){ task in
                    HStack{
                        if editMode {
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                            Button("Edit \(task.getName())"){
                                editTask = task
                                editReady = true
                            }
                        } else{
                            Text(task.getName())
                            Text(task.getType())
                            Text(task.getDate(),format: .dateTime.day().month())
                            if task.getBool(){
                                Text(task.getTime(),format: .dateTime.hour().minute())
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $editReady) {
                EditView(editTask: editTask)
            }
            .toolbar(){
                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic){Button("Edit"){
                    editMode.toggle()
                }}
            }
    }
}
```

Tried removing the Image, changing from List to Form, but not much else. Like it said this actually make no sense to me idk how this is happening.

Comment: Your last element is dependent on a boolean value(`if task.getBool(){ ... }`) while the others aren't

Comment: @clawesome Sorry if I wasnt clear. Not the last element of the HStack but of the ForEach loop. So if I have 5 elements in my schedule, the top 4 become a edit button while the bottom one stays the same. The task.getBool shouldnt matter if EditMode is on

Comment: Not sure but this might help.  Does Task conform to the Identifiable protocol? If so you can leave out the id:\.self, which may not be unique. If not I recommend you make it so.

Comment: @JosephLevy That works. Do you mind explaining why that is?

Comment: @WyattCake The ForEach needs unique ids or it will get things mixed up, especially with moves and deletes but also apparently in your case.  If you didn't want to change Task to Identifiable you could write: ForEach(schedule.indices,id: \.self){ i in ; let task = schedule[i]

Comment: @JosephLevy Thank you for explaining. Just like to know why shit works instead of just moving on. So could I have added a computed member id to Task? and then it would automatically use that? Or is that a different language im blending in

Comment: @WyattCake It will use any id you  define, effectively like id: \.id were written in the ForEach. The definition var id = UUID() is popularly used since it makes a unique id. I suppose if your computed id  were unique too, it would work.

Comment: I moved the comments with this explanation into an answer so this can get closure. Pun intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make Task conform to the Identifiable protocol and leave out the id:.self. The ForEach needs unique ids or it will get things mixed up, especially with moves and deletes but also apparently in your case. If you didn't want to change Task to Identifiable you could write: `ForEach(schedule.indices,id: .self){ i in  let task = schedule[i]`